# Sorting list using reflection

Tags: c#

I have a table and i want to do sorting function for each column.

Sorting has two direction asc and desc.

1) How can i sort columns using reflection?

```
List<Person> GetSortedList(List<Person> persons, string direction, string column)
{
    return persons.OrderBy(x => GetProperyByName(x, column)); //GetPropertyByName - ??
}
```

2) Also i want to do something what i can call chain of linq operators:

```
 List<Person> GetSortedList(List<Person> persons, string direction, string column)
    {
         var linqChain;

         if(direction=="up")
         {
             linqChain+=persons.OrderBy(x => GetProperyByName(x, column))
         }
         else
         {
             linqChain+=persons.OrderByDescending(x => GetProperyByName(x, column))
         }

         linqChain+=.Where(....);

         return linqChain.Execute();

    }
```

Comment: Why the [tag:javascript] tag?

Comment: The [tag:web-development] isn't needed either, since although you might be doing web development, that knowledge isn't needed to answer the question, and the question isn't related to it.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just writing js grid and forget that this question only about sorting c# list.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Because person field which we are using to order passsing to sort function as string(column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want to sort using string names of columns, use the [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library.

```
if (direction == "ASC")    
    return persons.OrderBy(column);
else
    return persons.OrderByDescending(column);
```

2) You can concatenate LINQ expressions together by using an expression object.

```
Expression linqChain = persons;

if (direction == "up")
{
    linqChain = linqChain.OrderBy(column);
}
else
{
    linqChain = linqChain.OrderByDescending(column);
}

linqChain = linqChain.Where(...);

return linqChain.Execute();
```

Answer (score 5):

try something like this

```
public void SortListByPropertyName<T>(List<T> list, bool isAscending, string propertyName) where T : IComparable
{
    var propInfo = typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    Comparison<T> asc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable) propInfo.GetValue(t1, null)).CompareTo(propInfo.GetValue(t2, null));
    Comparison<T> desc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable) propInfo.GetValue(t2, null)).CompareTo(propInfo.GetValue(t1, null));
    list.Sort(isAscending ? asc : desc);
}
```

Comment: I liked this one, it worked for me, nonetheless I realized I need to sort by multiple fields, not just one :(

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> return (direction == "desc" ? persons.OrderByDescending(x =>  x.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(x)).ToList() : persons.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(x)).ToList());