# Elegant way to sort a dataGridView binded to a class list in c#

Tags: list, sorting, compare

my problem is to find the way to sort dynamically a dataGridView with datasource binded to a list of objects, calling it in a way like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Sort((x,y) => x.getfield(e.ColumnIndex).CompareTo(y.getfield(e.ColumnIndex)))) ;
    }
```

I explain my case.
My class is so defined:

```
public class FileWorking
    {
        private string Host;
        private string Id;
        private string Path;
        private string Filename;
        private string Username;
        private string ModRW;
        private DateTime Starttime;
        private DateTime Endtime;
        private int Status;

        public string host { get => Host; set => Host = value; }
        public string id { get => Id; set => Id = value; }
        public string path { get => Path; set => Path = value; }
        public string filename { get => Filename; set => Filename = value; }
        public string username { get => Username; set => Username = value; }
        public string modRW { get => ModRW; set => ModRW = value; }
        public DateTime starttime { get => Starttime; set => Starttime = value; }
        public DateTime endtime { get => Endtime; set => Endtime = value; }
        public int stato {get => Stato; set => Stato=value;}
        public TimeSpan active { get => (Endtime - Starttime); }
}
```

Then the List:

```
public List<FileWorking> historyFiles;
```

After populating the list I show it with a dataGridView component:

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = historyFiles;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Now I want to sort dataGridView1 per column clicked.
I did it in this way (since dataGridView1.Sort(e.ColumnIndex) through an exception):

```
 private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
   switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText)
                {
                    case "host":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.host.CompareTo(y.host));
                        break;
                    case "id":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.id.CompareTo(y.id));
                        break;
                    case "username":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.username.CompareTo(y.username));
                        break;
                    case "modRW":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.modRW.CompareTo(y.modRW));
                        break;
                    case "starttime":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.starttime.CompareTo(y.starttime));
                        break;
                    case "path":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.path.CompareTo(y.path));
                        break;
                    case "filename":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.filename.CompareTo(y.filename));
                        break;
                    case "endtime":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.endtime.CompareTo(y.endtime));
                        break;
                    case "stato":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x,y) => x.stato.CompareTo(y.stato));
                        break;
                    case "active":
                        historyFiles.Sort((x, y) => x.active.CompareTo(y.active));
                        break;
                }

                dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

I understand this is not the best solution:
- compare is used for each field even if type are similar
- if I add some other properties I would add a specific lines in the switch
...

I tried with reflections implementing this function in FileWorking class:

```
public object getfield(int fieldindex)
        {
            Type t = this.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
            object prop =props.GetValue(fieldindex);
            return prop;

        }
```

but when I try calling like this I can't compile (actually object doesn't have CompareTo even if int, string, DateTime, TimeSpan yes...):

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        historyFiles.Sort((x,y) => x.getfield(e.ColumnIndex).CompareTo(y.getfield(e.ColumnIndex)))) ;
    }
```

Is there any way to do it?

thanks in advance,
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

Solved, basing  to this answer [6942512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942512/sorting-list-using-reflection), just in this way:

```
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var propInfo = typeof(FileWorking).GetProperty(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);
            Comparison<FileWorking> asc = (t1, t2) => ((IComparable)propInfo.GetValue(t1, null)).CompareTo(propInfo.GetValue(t2, null));
            historyFiles.Sort(asc);
        }
```