# Order by dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to make and order by with dynamic parameter, this is the code:

```
var res = from c in db.CUSTOMERS select c;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(direction))
      {
       var property = typeof(CUSTOMERS).GetProperty(sortBy);

       if(direction == "asc")
         {
            res = res.OrderBy(x => property.GetValue(x));
         }
      else
         {
           res = res.OrderBy(x => property.GetValue(x));
         } 
}

return res.ToList();
```

but I get this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

[image]

Comment: maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689239/5309228) can help you?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, the same error message :\

Comment: what version of EF are you using? maybe you've got an older version not supporting that feature yet. plus: have you tried the other answers? for example providing a string with the property name instead of a lambda referencing the property?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What database provider are you using? LINQ to databases uses `Expression` trees to translate C# code into SQL - there is no SQL for `GetValue` so it can't be translated.

Comment: The library mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6942654/13524307) might work for you.

Comment: @hous what are you trying to do? What is `property.GetValue(x)` supposed to mean? If you want to order by different properties, use different `OrderBy` calls.

Comment: This is the first time and the first week I use c# and asp.net, I don't know what are you asking about. I'll see with manager. thank you

Comment: @hous this isn't about C# or ASP.NET, it's about SQL, databases, Entity Framework and LINQ. ASP.NET is a web framework, it doesn't deal with database queries. Data access is the job of ADO.NET and ORMs like Entity Framework. LINQ is a convenient language that eventually gets translated to SQL for execution on the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do sorting on the Server Side, you have to correct expression.

```cs
 var query = from c in db.CUSTOMERS select c;
    
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(direction))
 {
    query = query.ApplyOrderBy(new [] {Tuple.Create(sortBy, direction != "asc")});
 }

 return query.ToList();
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyOrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, bool>> order)
    {
        var expr = ApplyOrderBy(typeof(T), query.Expression, order);
        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expr);
    }

    static Expression MakePropPath(Expression objExpression, string path)
    {
        return path.Split('.').Aggregate(objExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    }

    static Expression ApplyOrderBy(Type entityType, Expression queryExpr, IEnumerable<Tuple<string, bool>> order)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e");
        var isFirst = true;
        foreach (var tuple in order)
        {
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(MakePropPath(param, tuple.Item1), param);
            var methodName =
                isFirst ? tuple.Item2 ? nameof(Queryable.OrderByDescending) : nameof(Queryable.OrderBy)
                : tuple.Item2 ? nameof(Queryable.ThenByDescending) : nameof(Queryable.ThenBy);

            queryExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, new[] { entityType, lambda.Body.Type }, queryExpr, lambda);
            isFirst = false;
        }

        return queryExpr;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I'll test it Monday at the work and tell you. thanks