# How orderBy dynamically, based on navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

```
var query = TableNoTracking;
query = query
            .Include(r => r.UserRoles).ThenInclude(o => o.Role)
            .Include(c => c.Photos.Where(x => x.IsMain))
            .Include(w => w.Wallets);
```

my sort part is like below and I want handle sorting dynamically

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterUser.SortBy))
            {
                switch (filterUser.Reverse)
                {
                    //reverse
                    case true:
                        switch (filterUser.SortBy)
                        {
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.InventorySum:
                                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.Inventory).Sum());
                                break;
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.InterMoneySum:
                                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.InterMoney).Sum());
                                break;
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.ExitMoneySum:
                                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.ExitMoney).Sum());
                                break;
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.OnExitMoneySum:
                                query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.OnExitMoney).Sum());
                                break;
                        }

                        break;
                    case false:
                        switch (filterUser.SortBy)
                        {
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.InventorySum:
                                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.Inventory).Sum());
                                break;
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.InterMoneySum:
                                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.InterMoney).Sum());
                                break;
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.ExitMoneySum:
                                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.ExitMoney).Sum());
                                break;
                            case UserNavigationPropsForSort.OnExitMoneySum:
                                query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Wallets.Select(y => y.OnExitMoney).Sum());
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

I include several entities, now I want to order this query dynamically based on included properties, for example inventory in wallet.
i tried dynamic linq library but it dont work for this situation;

How can I do this?

Comment: I din't get question. Could you please show how do you plan sort without dynamic realisation? Just LINQ query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by dynamic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849281/order-by-dynamic-parameter)

Comment: no not worked for me.I edit question for better understanding

Comment: So, you have hidden a lot of details. Dynamic realisation a little bit tricky and better leave it as is. If you have a lot of such sorting techniques, add more examples to understand complexity of common solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @nbokmans and @Svyatoslav Danyliv. I used Expression instead of Func and now code work.

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterUser.SortBy))
            {
                if (filterUser.SortableProperties.Any(x =>
                    string.Equals(x, filterUser.SortBy, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    Expression<Func<User, int>> exp = filterUser.SortBy switch
                    {
                        UserNavigationPropsForSort.InventorySum => w => w.Wallets.Select(x => x.Inventory).Sum(),
                        UserNavigationPropsForSort.InterMoneySum => w => w.Wallets.Select(x => x.InterMoney).Sum(),
                        UserNavigationPropsForSort.ExitMoneySum => w => w.Wallets.Select(x => x.ExitMoney).Sum(),
                        UserNavigationPropsForSort.OnExitMoneySum => w => w.Wallets.Select(x => x.OnExitMoney).Sum(),
                        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
                    };

                    query = filterUser.Reverse ? query.OrderByDescending(exp) : query.OrderBy(exp);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nicely done! This is very similar to what I was gonna propose changing my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure it's possible to do it fully dynamic without setting up a mapping between `UserNavigationPropsForSort` and a `Wallet` property.

- Unless you want to get into expression tree building, which I suspect is overkill for what you're actually trying to do. If not, refer to docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees-building

What I've done is made your code a bit more concise and expandable:

```
            var query = TableNoTracking;
            query = query
                .Include(r => r.UserRoles).ThenInclude(o => o.Role)
                .Include(c => c.Photos.Where(x => x.IsMain))
                .Include(w => w.Wallets);
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterUser.SortBy.ToString()))
            {
                Func<Wallet, decimal> sortByToProperty = filterUser.SortBy switch
                {
                    UserNavigationPropsForSort.InventorySum => w => w.Inventory,
                    UserNavigationPropsForSort.InterMoneySum => w => w.InterMoney,
                    UserNavigationPropsForSort.ExitMoneySum => w => w.ExitMoney,
                    UserNavigationPropsForSort.OnExitMoneySum => w => w.OnExitMoney,
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
                };

                query = filterUser.Reverse
                    ? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Wallets.Select(sortByToProperty).Sum())
                    : query.OrderBy(x => x.Wallets.Select(sortByToProperty).Sum());
            }
```

If, at any point, you want to add more properties to sort by, you can expand the `sortByToProperty` switch.

Please let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: Good start, but you have to deal with Expression instead of pure delegates.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm not in a position to test it, but since the `Func<Wallet, decimal> sortByToProperty` is used *inside* the query's `Select` (which is an `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`), I think it might work

Comment: How easy to write this via `IEnumerable` ;) With `IQueryable` such trick will not work.

Comment: tnq,its cleaner way...i test it but get this error

Comment: "Expression of type 'System.Func`2[FarsiPay.Entities.MainDb.User.Wallet,System.Int32]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[FarsiPay.Entities.MainDb.User.Wallet,System.Int32]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32] Select[Wallet,Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FarsiPay.Entities.MainDb.User.Wallet], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[FarsiPay.Entities.MainDb.User.Wallet,System.Int32]])' (Parameter 'arg1')"