# Improve Linq query when sorting UWP DataGrid

Tags: linq, uwp, datagrid

I implemented sorting in a UWP DataGrid following the example at [How to: Group, sort and filter data in the DataGrid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/group_sort_filter#2-sorting)

The column sorting event uses a Tag from the data column header to run the specific Linq query, e.g., Tag=“Country”.

My hypothetical datagrid has 3 fields “Country”, “Name”, “Height”, so in order to add sorting to all 3 fields, I would need to duplicate the logic and query for each field with only the “orderby field” being different. Is there a better solution?

```
if (e.Column.Tag.ToString() == "Country") 
{
  mydg.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Mountain>(
  from item in myData
  orderby item.Country ascending 
  select item);
 }
```

Comment: As mentioned, there are a lot of implementations on SO, and [mine also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850085/10646316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T> / IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet-iqueryablet).

You can build up the basic `IQueryable<>`, dynamically apply a sort based on user selected sort preferences, and then pass the resulting query on as the `ItemSource`.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at it. There’s some pros and cons in the discussion with one saying it takes 29 ms. I don’t know if that’s faster than my redundant code as is, but mostly the code is a bit aged, and I really don’t want to build a custom ORM wrapper. But I will experiment with it.