# Sort and filter with varying key .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, pagination

I have a table in the frontend with multiple columns and pagination. The user should be able to sort which columns he wants, and if he moves to the next page, that page should also be sorted by the given column.

My approach with a single sort key and pagination:

```
public List<Person> GetPersons(int page, int numPerPage)
{
   return _context.Person
                  .OrderByDescending(p => p.FirstName)
                  .Skip(page*numPerPage)
                  .Take(numPerPage)
}
```

This is limited to only sorting by `FirstName`, but how can I do this with e.g. `LastName`, `Address` etc...?

Comment: Could you explain further? Where should I add this predicate? :)

Comment: Check out [the documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-6.0), they are helpful. If you have tried it and still need help, please update your post to include what you've tried.

Comment: Check this [ApplyOrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850085/10646316) implementation.

Comment: My problem is also with searching. How do I apply a good search without loading everything into the client at once?

Comment: @newbie don't force people to guess. You can pass an arbitrary expression to Enumerable's OrderBy. In LINQ, whether that works or not depends on the underlying provider. If you ask how to use a generic expression to sort a *collection* people will tell you that's already available. If you say you use *Entity Framework*, it's a *completely* different problem. Even valid expressions may fail if you pass them around as parameters.  In that case you can use[LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#plugging-expressions-into-entitysets--entitycollections-the-problem) to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderbydescending?view=net-6.0) takes a function with 2 type parameters: `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` where `TKey` represents the type of the key returned by the expression.

Therefore, you could pass an expression to your method and use in the OrderBy:

```
public List<Person> GetPersons<TKey>(int page, int numPerPage, 
                                     Expression<Func<Person, TKey>> orderByDesc)
{
    return _context.Person
                   .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                   .Skip(page*numPerPage)
                   .Take(numPerPage);
}
```

The `TKey` type parameter is inferred by the expression. So, it can be used as below:

```
var byName = GetPersons(page, pageSize, p => p.FirstName);
var byDate = GetPersons(page, pageSize, p => p.DateOfBirth);
var byHeight = GetPersons(page, pageSize, p => p.Height);
```

---

If you want to apply a filter/search then add a new expression to the method and use `Where`:

```
public List<Person> GetPersons<TKey>(int page, int numPerPage,
                                     Expression<Func<Person, bool>> filter,
                                     Expression<Func<Person, TKey>> orderByDesc)
{
    return _context.Person
                   .Where(filter)
                   .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                   .Skip(page*numPerPage)
                   .Take(numPerPage);
}
// filter by FirstName, order by LastName
var filtered = GetPersons(page, pageSize, 
                 p => p.FirstName == "Bob", // filter
                 p => p.LastName);          // orderBy
```

Comment: Very clean solution for sorting. But what about searching?

Comment: It's almost the same for filtering/searching except you use bool instead of `TKey`. For example, `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> filter` -> `_context.Person.Where(filter)...` @newbie

Comment: How can I initialize this? Expression<Func<Person, TKey>> column = defaultValue

Answer (score 2):

Try this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
    string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
    return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
}
```

And you can pass property name as a string like `FirstName`, `LastName` or `Address` etc.. Thus you can order `Persons` dynamically.

```
public List<Person> GetPersons(int page, int numPerPage, string orderFieldName)
{
   return _context.Person
                  .OrderByField(orderFieldName, false)
                  .Skip(page*numPerPage)
                  .Take(numPerPage)
}
```

See: [How to use expression trees to build dynamic queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries)

EDIT:

Another possible solution is using `System.Linq.Dynamic` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660293/5519709