# Entity Framework Core Dynamic Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-core

I have been searching and I have not seen an example like this.

I want to query a Model table to retrieve all Models from German manufacturers.

My data structure is Model Table has a Navigation Property called "Manufacturer" and an FK called "IdManufacturer"

A Manufacturer Has a Navigation Property called "Origin" and an FK called IdOrigin.

I would like to have a query that includes a where clause something like this:

```cs
(m => m.Manufacturer.Origin.Name == "German");
```

I would like this to be dynamically created at run time.  Not only the lookup value might change, but the next time even the fields may change to, for example:
`(m.Type.Name == "SUV")`;

Finally, there will not necessarily be a UI associated with this request, it may be generated in code.

Please don't get too hung up on the business of it, I am hoping this made up example will be simple to understand.

Any suggestions on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated.  Any general thoughts on performance would be created.

Comment: What you have tried and where do you stuck? SO is full of such answers.

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74274206/c-sharp-ef-core-reflection-order) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849281/order-by-dynamic-parameter/65850085#65850085)

Comment: Consider whether you really need to build the expression tree dynamically, or if simply building the `IQueryable<T>` dynamically would be sufficient, as in `if (request.Origin is not null) query = query.Where(m.Manufacturer.Origin.Name == request.Origin);` Dynamically building expression trees requires that you trust the input *completely* or put limits on what can be accessed.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses.

This is the code I am working with so far.  It is not the ultimate solution, but it is designed to educate me a bit on how this should work:

IList<Model> modelCollection;

query = query.Where("Manufacturer.Origin.Name=@0", "German");  //Doesn't Work

query = query.Where(a => a.Manufacturer.Origin.Name == "German"); //Doesnt Work

modelCollection= await query.ToListAsync();

And, by doesn't work, provides 0 results when the data is out there.

This is a time where I know this and examples have to be very common, just not finding them.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:
I have a model `RouteList`, in this model I created `Expression`:

```
public static Expression<Func<RouteList, bool>> FilterByDateOrShiftCode(RoutesFilterViewModel filter)
{
    Expression<Func<RouteList, bool>> result = rl => true;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.ShiftCode))
    {
        result = rl => rl.RouteListDate.Date >= filter.From.Date && rl.RouteListDate.Date <= filter.To.Date && rl.User.Id == filter.User.Id;
    }
    else
    {
        result = rl => rl.ShiftCode == filter.ShiftCode && rl.User.Id == filter.User.Id;
    }
```

Place where I use it:

```
model.RouteLists = await _context.RouteLists
    .Include(rl => rl.Status)
    .Include(rl => rl.User)
    .Include(rl => rl.RouteListRows).ThenInclude(rlr => rlr.Address)
    .Where(RouteList.FilterByDateOrShiftCode(filter))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Speed of executing grow in several times.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  A lot of this is new to me and I am reviewing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple extension method. Note that this realization will work only with sting properties.

Usage:

```cs
query = query.Where("Manufacturer.Origin.Name", "German");
```

Realization:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propPath, string value)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        // e.Prop1.Prop2 == value
        var body = Expression.Equal(MakePropPath(param, propPath), Expression.Constant(value));
        // e => e.Prop1.Prop2 == value
        var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);

        return query.Where(predicateLambda);
    }

    static Expression MakePropPath(Expression objExpression, string path)
    {
        return path.Split('.').Aggregate(objExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  A lot of this is new to me and I am reviewing it right now.

Comment: I am working with this suggestion, please know that this is my first extension.

I am getting a compile error for each "<T>" saying that "Type or Namespace T could not be found".  I attempted changing each to "<Type>" and is compiling, however I am getting a run-time 500 error with this message:  "No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. '"

Comment: I am sure this is simple, just not what I have done so far.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: After days of overlooking something that was so obvious, I think I found the problem -- something that I just couldn't see.

However, I do appreciate the suggestions.  I am very likely going to incorporate these into my design.  Once I have confirmed that this works, I will answer my question.

Comment: Corrected answer. Missed generic argument. Written from memory.

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv:  Thank you for your follow up.  This seems to be working and is beyond helpful.

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv:  As I said, this has been helpful.  I am looking to make a change and am requesting any suggestions you might have, including even if you think this is a good idea.

The change is to send a list of PropertyPath/Values and to have the code convert that into a "and" or and "or".

Thanks again.