# How to Filter a table in EF Core dynamically by some properties selected by client

Tags: c#, entity-framework, filter

I want to find some records in a table with a list of items that user selected to filter

I have try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> FilterByProperties<TEntity>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames, IEnumerable<object> propertyValues)
  {
   var predicate = propertyNames.SelectMany(propertyName => propertyValues.Select(propertyValue => (Func<TEntity, bool>)(() =>
  {
    return entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(entity, null) == propertyValue;
})));

return entities.Where(predicate.Any);
  }




  var people = new List<Person>
 {
new Person() { Name = "John Smith", Age = 25, Address = "123 Main Street" },
new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 21, Address = "456 Elm Street" },
new Person() { Name = "Peter Jones", Age = 31, Address = "789 Oak Street" }
 };

  var filteredPeople = people.FilterByProperties(propertyNames: new[] { "Name", "Age" }, propertyValues: new[] { "John Smith", 25 });

   // filteredPeople now contains the following object:
  // { Name = "John Smith", Age = 25, Address = "123 Main Street" }
```

But I didn't get something.

Can anyone write a runnable code with an example. I stocked in this issue for some days

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74308141/entity-framework-core-dynamic-where-clause

Comment: it is not what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a class which has all possible filtration options and send it with the request.

Example:

```
public class FiltrationParameters 
{
    public FiltrationParameters() => OrderBy = "name";
    public string? SearchTerm { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }

//Add all the properties a client could add

}
```

Change the value of the properties which client want to filter. Leave value of other properties as null

Sending to Api

- Method 1: You can send these in the Httpget method as query strings
- Method 2: You can send this as object in the HttpPost method

After you receive all the filtration properties you can check only the values and which is not null and handle the filter

```
var entities = await FindAll(trackChanges).ToListAsync();

if (filtrationParameters.Age != null) entities = entities.Where(x => x.Age == filtrationParameters.Age).ToList();

//And add other conditions like this
```

It is easy to handle the future changes. If the client asked to add another filtration option, then simply add a property to the filtration class and handle it if it is not null.

Comment: so I want to replace  x.Age with x[parameter] in "entities.Where(x => x.Age == "

Comment: Not really. As I mentioned in the answer, you should have a class with all the possible filtration options, such as Age, Name Etc. Then you need to check each property that is not null and apply filters.

var entities = await FindAll(trackChanges).ToListAsync();

if (filtrationParameters.Age != null) entities = entities. Where(x => x.Age == filtrationParameters.Age).ToList();

if (filtrationParameters.Name!= null) entities = entities. Where(x => x.Name== filtrationParameters.Name).ToList();

like on

Comment: I did that by . var ss = result.asQueryable(); var filterResult = ss.Where("string of every parameter dynamic ").toList();