# Can't get sorting expression to evaluate correctly when using nested properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I have a linq query:

```
DbSet<GeneralGroup>()
.Where(...)
...
.Select(res => new GeneralGroupResult{ 
        Id = result.Id,        
        Statistics = new Statistics(
            res.GeneralCount,
            res.SpecificCount
        )        
    });
```

Once I run it in database context with `.ToListAsync()`, it works fine.

I need to support dynamic sorting. For example, when I receive `Id`, I generate the following expression:

```
{Param_0 => Convert(Param_0.Id, Object)}
```

Then I apply it to query with

```
query.OrderBy(expression)
```

So it becomes like this:

```
    ...
    .Select(res => new GeneralGroupResult{ 
            Id = result.Id,        
            Statistics = new Statistics(
                res.GeneralCount,
                res.SpecificCount
            )        
        })
   .OrderBy(namelessParameter{0} => (object)namelessParameter{0}.Id)
```

And that also works fine.

Same approach doesn't work with nested properties though. When I receive `Statistics.SpecificCount` and generate expression for it:

```
{Param_0 => Convert(Param_0.Statistics.SpecificCount, Object)}
```

I get this as evaluated expression:

```
        ...
        .Select(res => new GeneralGroupResult{ 
                Id = result.Id,        
                Statistics = new Statistics(
                    res.GeneralCount,
                    res.SpecificCount
                )        
            })
 .OrderBy(namelessParameter{0} => (object)namelessParameter{0}.Statistics.SpecificCount)
```

Which looks correct, but fails to translate to SQL with the following error:

```
Error creating query string: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GeneralGroup>()
    .Where(...)
     ...
    .OrderBy(ti2 => (object)new Statistics(
        ti2.Inner.SpecificCount, 
        ti2.Inner.GeneralCount
    ).SpecificCount)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information..
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by dynamic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849281/order-by-dynamic-parameter)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I don't see it having anything to do with nested properties. I do everything else in similar way

Comment: Just name properties using dots, `query.ApplyOrderBy(new [] {Tuple.Create("Inner.SpecificCount", direction != "asc")});`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I actually copied your code entirely and I get the same "expression could not be translated"   error