# Using Entity Framework 6 to populate list in object is resulting in empty list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on a proof of concept for a web application for a group of friends. I'm using a mock database with dummy data just so I can test my API. I'm trying to populate a list of an object "Award" randomly using data from my mock database.

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1,50))
{
    db.Troopers.Add(new Trooper 
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Trooper {i}",
        Callsign = $"TK-{i}",
        Awards = db.Awards.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList()
    };
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

The issue is Awards is always an empty list. I've tested the `db.Awards.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList()` part on its own and it returns values. I don't understand why the list is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
Debug.WriteLine(db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
```

before I save the changes and I'm able to see that even though awards are being populated and added to the Awards list with both of the solutions provided below, only the last two entries are actually keeping them. Well, it's keeping the Ids and dropping the Award names completely.

```
Trooper {Id: 1} Added
  Id: 1 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 1'
  Callsign: 'TK-1'
  Awards: []
Trooper {Id: 2} Added
  Id: 2 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 2'
  Callsign: 'TK-2'
  Awards: []
Trooper {Id: 3} Added
  Id: 3 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 3'
  Callsign: 'TK-3'
  Awards: []
...
Trooper {Id: 49} Added
  Id: 49 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 49'
  Callsign: 'TK-49'
  Awards: [{Id: 3}]
Trooper {Id: 50} Added
  Id: 50 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 50'
  Callsign: 'TK-50'
  Awards: [{Id: 1}, {Id: 2}]
```

Why would it not keep the full Award object for every Trooper? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't post multiple questions at the same time. You'll find *dozens* of duplicates for the second question. EF translates LINQ queries to SQL and there's no way for the *database* to call client-side functions. If you search for dynamic LINQ queries you'll find a lot of answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order by dynamic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849281/order-by-dynamic-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be related to how Entity Framework is tracking changes and handling the relationship between Trooper and Award entities. When you call `db.Awards.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList()`, you are retrieving a list of awards, but Entity Framework may not be automatically tracking the relationship between the Trooper and the retrieved awards.

To ensure that the relationship is correctly established and tracked by Entity Framework, you can try attaching the awards to the context before assigning them to the Awards property of the Trooper object.

i.e.

```cs
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 50))
{
    var trooper = new Trooper
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Trooper {i}",
        Callsign = $"TK-{i}"
    };

    var awards = db.Awards.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList();
    
    // Attach the awards to the context
    foreach (var award in awards)
    {
        db.Awards.Attach(award);
    }

    trooper.Awards = awards;
    db.Troopers.Add(trooper);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

For your 2nd question, ask another one. That's an entirely different problem.

Comment: I reposted my question so that it's more focused and added more information. I tried your solution and ended up with a mostly empty list still, even though I can see that the list was populated in the Trooper object before I saved the changes. Could you possibly look at my new post and comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841585/using-entity-framework-6-to-populate-list-in-object-is-resulting-in-mostly-empty?noredirect=1#comment137230876_77841585

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Question 1: Before the loop, ensure that the awards data is loaded into memory, and then you can use it within the loop.

```
var awardsList = db.Awards.ToList();

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 50))
{
    db.Troopers.Add(new Trooper
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Trooper {i}",
        Callsign = $"TK-{i}",
        Awards = awardsList.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList()
    });
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I reposted my question so that it's more focused and added more information. I tried your solution and ended up with an empty list still, even though I can see that the list was populated in the Trooper object before I saved the changes. Could you possibly look at my new post and comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841585/using-entity-framework-6-to-populate-list-in-object-is-resulting-in-mostly-empty