# Using Entity Framework 6 to populate list in object is resulting in mostly empty list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had to make a new question since my last post wasn't focused enough.
I'm working on a proof of concept for a web application for a group of friends. I'm using a mock database with dummy data just so I can test my API. I'm trying to populate a list of an object "Award" randomly using data from my mock database. NOTE: My actual database would have a table for AwardsToTroopers to deal with the many-to-many relationship. I'm not doing that here because this is just a mock up to show how much better a dedicated web application would be versus a thousand Google Sheets all linked to each other.

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1,50))
{
    db.Troopers.Add(new Trooper 
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Trooper {i}",
        Callsign = $"TK-{i}",
        Awards = db.Awards.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList()
    };
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

With both the solutions offered by my last post, I was able to see that the Awards list was being populated and properly attached to the Trooper. However, when I would get a list of all the Troopers from the database, the Awards list would be empty.

I tried this written by @Amit Mohanty

```
var awardsList = db.Awards.ToList();

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 50))
{
    db.Troopers.Add(new Trooper
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Trooper {i}",
        Callsign = $"TK-{i}",
        Awards = awardsList.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList()
    });
}
```

and this written by @aiapatag

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 50))
{
    var trooper = new Trooper
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = $"Trooper {i}",
        Callsign = $"TK-{i}"
    };

    var awards = db.Awards.Where(award => i % award.Id == 0).ToList();
    
    // Attach the awards to the context
    foreach (var award in awards)
    {
        db.Awards.Attach(award);
    }

    trooper.Awards = awards;
    db.Troopers.Add(trooper);
}
```

and added

```
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
Debug.WriteLine(db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
```

before I save the changes. With the debugger I'm able to see that only the last two entries are actually keeping the Awards. Sort of. It's keeping the Award Id but dropping the Name completely.

```
Trooper {Id: 1} Added
  Id: 1 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 1'
  Callsign: 'TK-1'
  Awards: []
Trooper {Id: 2} Added
  Id: 2 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 2'
  Callsign: 'TK-2'
  Awards: []
Trooper {Id: 3} Added
  Id: 3 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 3'
  Callsign: 'TK-3'
  Awards: []
...
Trooper {Id: 49} Added
  Id: 49 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 49'
  Callsign: 'TK-49'
  Awards: [{Id: 3}]
Trooper {Id: 50} Added
  Id: 50 PK
  Name: 'Trooper 50'
  Callsign: 'TK-50'
  Awards: [{Id: 1}, {Id: 2}]
```

Why is it not keeping the full Award object for every Trooper? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: At the request of @Yitz here are my definitions for Trooper and Award.

Trooper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ORBAT.Lib
{
    public class Trooper
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }

        public String Callsign { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Award> Awards { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Award.cs

```
using System;

namespace ORBAT.Lib
{
    public class Award
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a many-to-many relationship, but you have a one-to-many relationship. Can you post the definitions for Trooper and Award?

Comment: @Yitz I've edited my question to include the definitions for both classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a one-to-many relationship, i.e. a `Trooper` can have many `Award`s but an `Award` can only belong to one `Trooper`. In order to create a many-to-many relationship, you need to add a `Troopers` collection to your `Award` class:

```
public class Award
{
    //...

    public virtual ICollection<Trooper> Troopers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding that one line fixed everything that I've been pulling my hair out over.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. Your third example was very close. Something like this should work:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 50)) {
   var trooper = new Trooper {
      Id = i,
      Name = $"Trooper {i}",
      Callsign = $"TK-{i}"
   };

   var awards = 
      db
      .Awards
      .Where(award => i % award.Id == 0);
    
   foreach (var award in awards)
      trooper.Awards.Add(award);

   db.Troopers.Add(trooper);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

This is assuming your model is correct.

In your `Trooper` class, you should also instantiate the collection navigation property:

```
...
public virtual ICollection<Award> Awards { get; } = new List<Award>();
...
```

You may also want to build a lookup structure once for `Award`s rather than run a query for each `Trooper`.